# MKMapview ios not showing current location when app is loaded first time

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview, coordinates

I have a `MKMapView` on my app. This is iOS6.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    .....
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"Update locations is hit");
    NSLog(@"379 the locations count is %d",locations.count);

    CLLocation *obj = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"the lat is %f", obj.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"the long is %f", obj.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"the horizontal accuracy is %f",obj.horizontalAccuracy);
    NSLog(@"the vertical accuracty is %f",obj.verticalAccuracy);
    if (obj.coordinate.latitude != 0 && obj.coordinate.longitude != 0)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D currrentCoordinates ;
        currrentCoordinates.latitude = obj.coordinate.latitude;
        currrentCoordinates.longitude = obj.coordinate.longitude;
    }
    ....more computation
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

When I first load the app, my location is showing little far away. Some times miles away. I also have a reset location button and if I click that map shows correct location. This is what I have in reset location button click:

```
- (IBAction)btnResetLocationClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

So how do I make the app get the correct current location on load up itself. Is there a way for the app to tell the map to wait for few milliseconds and then update. Or any other idea? Please let me know. If you need more information, please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to:

- do not turn off location services in `didUpdateLocations` automatically, but rather;
- turn off location services in `didUpdateLocations` only if you're sufficiently happy with the `horizontalAccuracy`; and
- even if you don't get the desired accuracy, turn off location services after a certain amount of time has passed.

Thus, `didUpdateLocations` might look like:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    // do whatever you want with the location

    // finally turn off location services if we're close enough
    //
    // I'm using 100m; maybe that's too far for you, but 5m is probably too small
    // as you frequently never get that accurate of a location

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 && location.horizontalAccuracy < 100)
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

And then in `viewDidLoad`, turn if off after a certain period of time has passed (you might want to check some status variable that you set if you've already turned off location services):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    .....
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 60.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    });
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

I don't see where you're updating your map to be around your location. I'd expect to see something like:

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = location.coordinate;
```

or like:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 300, 300);
[self.mapView setRegion:region];
```

I'd also suggest, rather than turning off location services immediately (since frequently the first few locations are not that accurate), leave it on for a bit and let it hone in on your location until the `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` fall within a certain predetermined limit. Look at those accuracy figures for a few calls to `didUpdateLocations` and you'll see what I mean.

I originally thought you were getting a negative `horizontalAccuracy` at which point I suggested implementing [`didFailToLocateUserWithError`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3adidFailToLocateUserWithError%3a) because according to [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/horizontalAccuracy), "A negative value indicates that the location’s latitude and longitude are invalid." Hopefully you get an error that describes what the issue is. Even if you're not currently getting a negative `horizontalAccuracy`, you might want to implement this method, just to make sure you're handling any errors correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Well i am taking the coordinates and passing them to a method where i form a MKMapView and set its coordinates. Also i logged vertical and horizontal accuracies.They came out -1 and 5 consistently. I was debugging and i put a breakpoint in didUpdateLocations and -1 and 5 kept logging. Should both the accuracies be greater than 0.?

Comment: @Rob.What can i do to make them greater than 0.

Comment: @Phanindar Is horizontal (the lat and long accuracy) negative? Or is the vertical (the altitude) negative? You probably don't care about the latter (though I'm not sure how it gets altitude if it doesn't know where you are), but the former is pretty important. I'm guessing you're just not getting a good GPS signal (hence my suggestion of trying turning on wifi, or turning it off if you have it on).

Comment: The vertical accuracy is negative.Horizontal is positive..always 5. So i should check coordinates>0 and just horizontal accuracy>0. Will that do?

Comment: @Phanindar Yes. But going back to your original question, you want to (a) turn on location services; (b) keep monitoring locations until you get a sufficiently low (but positive) `horizontalAccuracy`; and (c) have a timer that turns off location services after a period of time because even if you don't have the ideal accuracy, it's probably as accurate as it's going to get. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Implemented that. Will test it out.

Comment: @Phanindar By the way, when you say `horizontalAccuracy` is always 5 and `verticalAccuracy` is -1, I assume that's what you're seeing on the simulator. On device is will vary more than that, I find. Location services is something where testing on physical devices is even more critical than usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the GPS in the iPhone more accurate in your app, but you can check that the result *is* accurate before carrying on. Right now you're only checking the lat and long aren't 0, but if you check `obj`'s horizontalAccuracy then you'll know when the location information is good enough. Don't `stopUpdatingLoation` until that happens.